# How to install composer on live server cpanel to make local installed library work on live

Tags: php, composer-php, yii1.x

I uploaded my yii1 project to live server,there was a library (which I have installed it on local machine using composer) give an error (`class not found`), what I did was:

1. Ensure that in my file access to autoload file in library correctly.
2. Contacting with support team of hosting company to install composer on the server, they replied "you have to use dedicated server or vps to complete this action".

(The library is a client library for LinkedIn).

Should I install composer using ssh protocol on the server? Or is there another solution?

Comment: If you have shell access then yes, you should be able to install Composer to your user directory and use it from there.

Comment: ok shell access is given from server administrator?, in cpanel at server i found 'ssh access' section, in that section i generated public and private keys,is it useful and how to use it with putty in windows, how can i add this  keys?do i need more permissions from server hosting?

Comment: It sounds like you've already got the access you need. Google "using putty with openssh keys" and go from there. (You may have to convert the keys to PuTTY's format…)

Answer (score 0):

> I uploaded my yii1 project to live server

But not including all dependencies...

The unresolved or missing dependency just indicates that you didn't resolve the dependencies correctly before deployment or that the packaging wasn't including the dependency.

> Should I install composer using ssh protocol on the server? Or is there another solution?

You don't need Composer on the production machine at all.

Solution: Package your application completely including all dependencies.

Please resolve all Composer dependencies, so that the app runs in the development/packaging stage. Package correctly, then deploy.